# JQuery Function Asp.net pass by reference

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I am trying to call a function from Code Behind. The Jquery function I am trying to call is the JSON editor jQuery plugin as seen here: http://www.daviddurman.com/jquery-json-editor-plugin.html and the source can be found here: https://github.com/DavidDurman/FlexiJsonEditor

In my aspx file I have something like ..

```
<div id="editor" class="json-editor"></div> 
<pre id="json"></pre>
<script src="Scripts/json/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/json/jquery.jsoneditor.js"></script>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="jsonlabel" Width="400"></asp:Label>
```

In my codebehind I set "result" and I call this

```
string jquerystring = "var json = "+result+";" + "$('#editor').jsonEditor(json, change: function() { $('#jsonlabel').text(JSON.stringify(json));} });";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "json", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquerystring +"</script>");
```

So basically I am trying to update the 'jsonlabel' text when 'json' changes. The thing is the 'json' object always remains the same.. I know that the change function() is being called whenever I make edits (I tried using a messagebox to prove this) but for some reason the 'json' object always stays the same.. and hence, my 'jsonlabel' always has the value of the original 'resulstring'

Comment: It's difficult to follow the logic here.  What is intended to happen client-side and what is intended to happen server-side?  Are the client-side changes simply being lost when a server-side post occurs?

Comment: the server generates the 'result' string (which is a JSON string) and calls the script. The script generates a view based on the 'result' string. The user can edit and modify the view and whenever a change happens to the view, the change function() should be called. And yeah, the client side changes are being lost.

Comment: When you do a post-back, in what way do you have the server-side code respond to client-side changes?  That is, how do you update the server-side code with those changes?  If no state has changed server-side related to this client-side functionality then it's always going to render it the same way.

Comment: Is there any way I can listen for changes to that variable in the server side during postback?

Comment: Also there is no postback happening when the change function gets called.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared more complete code (both client-side and server-side) and explained more clearly the order of events taking place.  It sounds like there's just a misunderstanding of the difference between server-side and client-side code, but the current information doesn't give a complete enough picture of what's happening.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it. I misread the documentation -> http://forums.asp.net/post/5456160.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it. I misread the documentation -> http://forums.asp.net/post/5456160.aspx